# Newtonsoft.Json deserializing multiple objects from stream

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How can I deserialize multiple json objects from stream, when there's other text between jsons.
In stream I have the following content:

```
Stuff that is not JSON

{"a": 1, "b": 2}

Stuff that is not JSON either

{"a": 3, "b": 4}
```

I would like to parse out those two json objects.

Answer (score 1):

Since this isn't a native JSON, you're going to have to do some labor work manually, though it shouldn't be difficult.

You can pass your stream into a `StreamReader` and skip two the first two lines:

```
var streamReader = new StreamReader(yourStream);

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    streamReader.ReadLine();
}

var jsonLine = textFile.ReadLine();
var yourObject = JsonConvert.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonLine);
```

Do this for both the lines. If you have a longer JSON with a constant between the lines, you can use a `while` loop instead with a modulo.

Note i parsed to `dynamic`, though you can parse this into any strongly typed type you have.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I want to work with streams. Reading whole line of json would create performance problem I want avoid. (Because those json lines are rather long)

Comment: This is working with a stream. You could use `Read` instrad of `ReadLine`. Could you please post a more accurate example?

Comment: Your solution is forcing me to allocate large strings (whole json is on one line, and it can be very big). I wanted to use `StreamReader` and `JsonTextReader` but they are both buffered readers, which means I cannot use them alternately. My solution that almost works now required me to implement non buffered "StreamReader" that is then used in JsonTextReader. I will post it when it's done. But maybe there's a better way.

Comment: I see. You should of mentioned the issue with the large string in your question.